# Is VC++ still broken Sequentially-Consistent-wise?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, concurrency, compiler-optimization

I watched (most of) [Herb Sutter's the atmoic<> weapons video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-2-of-2), and I wanted to test the "conditional lock" with a loop inside sample. Apparently, although (if I understand correctly) the C++11 standard says the below example should work properly and be sequentially consistent, it is not.

**Before you read on, my question is: Is this correct? Is the compiler broken? Is my code broken - do I have a race condition here which I missed? How do I bypass this?**

I tried it on 3 different versions of Visual C++: VC10 professional, VC11 professional and VC12 Express (== Visual Studio 2013 Desktop Express).

Below is the code I used for the Visual Studio 2013. For the other versions I used boost instead of std, but the idea is the same.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

int a = 0;
std::mutex m;

void other()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(m);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2));
    a = 999999;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    std::cout << a << "\n";
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    bool work = (argc > 1);

    if (work)
    {
        m.lock();
    }

    std::thread th(other);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
    {
        if (i % 7 == 3)
        {
            if (work)
            {
                ++a;
            }
        }
    }

    if (work)
    {
        std::cout << a << "\n";
        m.unlock();
    }

    th.join();
}
```

To summarize the idea of the code: The global variable `a` is protected by the global mutex `m`. Assuming there are no command line arguments (`argc==1`) the thread which runs `other()` is the only one which is supposed to access the global variable `a`.

The correct output of the program is to print 999999.

However, because of the compiler loop optimization (using a register for in-loop increments and at the end of the loop copying the value back to `a`), `a` is modified by the assembly even though it's not supposed to.

This happened in all 3 VC versions, although in this code example in VC12 I had to plant some calls to `sleep()` to make it break.

Here's some of the assembly code (the adress of `a` in this run is `0x00f65498`):

**Loop initialization - value from `a` is copied into `edi`**

```
    27:     for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
00F61543  xor         esi,esi  
00F61545  mov         edi,dword ptr ds:[0F65498h]  
00F6154B  jmp         main+0C0h (0F61550h)  
00F6154D  lea         ecx,[ecx]  
    28:     {
    29:         if (i % 7 == 3)
```

**Increment within the condition, and after the loop copied back to the location of `a` unconditionally**

```
    30:         {
    31:             if (work)
00F61572  mov         al,byte ptr [esp+1Bh]  
00F61576  jne         main+0EDh (0F6157Dh)  
00F61578  test        al,al  
00F6157A  je          main+0EDh (0F6157Dh)  
    32:             {
    33:                 ++a;
00F6157C  inc         edi  
    27:     for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
00F6157D  inc         esi  
00F6157E  cmp         esi,5F5E100h  
00F61584  jl          main+0C0h (0F61550h)  
    32:             {
    33:                 ++a;
00F61586  mov         dword ptr ds:[0F65498h],edi  
    34:             }
```

And the output of the program is `0`.

Comment: The code looks fine. I can't see a _data race_.

Comment: And if you mark `a` as `volatile`?

Comment: @JAB C++ `volatile`, unlike Java `volatile`, has nothing to do with multi threading.

Comment: @delnan But it _does_ have to do with preventing compiler optimizations on a variable, like, say, caching a variable in a register.

Comment: @JAB it does not give you reordering guarantees except for accesses to just that variable. Really not the right tool for the job.

Comment: I think the title of the question should be about "still introducing data-races", not about "sequential consistency".

Comment: @JAB - apparently `volatile` cancels this specific optimization, so the program works as expected. However, it still means there's a compiler bug here

Comment: @RedAlert - Intel i7-4770K... And in any case, the affect is on the compiler, not the CPU

Comment: @nosid - as I see it (and please correct me if I'm wrong), 'data race free' is a property of the code, whereas 'sequential consistency' is a property of the generated instructions and the way the CPU executes them

Comment: @Asaf What happens if you compile with g++ rather than VC++? (Assuming you have some version of it easily available, via MinGW or whatever; if not then I don't have it set up on my local machine to test either so oh well.)

Comment: @JAB - nothing readily available. I tried using ideone, but it doesn't allow using multithreading...

Comment: @JAB: I have tested the code with GCC-4.9, and it produces correct code. The main function does not write to `a` if `work==false`.

Comment: @Asaf: Technically, you are right. Still, I think the title is not helpful. Apparently the problem with VC is, that it introduces a _write operation_ to a variable, where no _write operation_ should be.

Comment: Uhhh evil bug this, you're definitely right. VS2013 professional doesn't exhibit this behavior though for me.

Comment: @Hans What bug? If `work` he acquires the mutex before starting the other thread and only writes to it while holding the lock. If `!work` the main thread never writes or reads `a`.

Comment: @Voo - I'll try this next time I'm at work and have access to VS2013 professional. Thanks. Maybe it's part of `Some C++ compiler crashes and language conformance issues have been addressed` in this update: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2927432

Comment: @Asaf I don't use VS that much so I had to actually look up how to generate the assembly, but it may just be a timing thing. Just looking through the generated code now..

Comment: @Asaf VS2013 generates: `mov r8d,dword ptr [a (013F385768h)]; [...] inc r8d; mov dword ptr [a (013F385768h)],r8d ` for each loop iteration  (it unrolls the loop twice and generates reads only once per loop body  but writes twice). For 32-bit code it generates equivalent code, so apparently they fixed it.

Comment: @Voo - is all of this done within the conditional `if (work)` ? In any case it seems like they cancelled this optimization completely, which is a shame, since there are other solutions (Sutter suggested a dirty bit). And thanks for your efforts :)

Comment: @Asaf Sorry yeah forgot the most important part - yes it is. [Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7670761/) is the assembly of the loop if you want to double check my work. Personally I'm exceedingly surprised that it doesn't hoist the check for `work` out of the loop - but I did compile in Release mode for x64 (and since /FA generates horrible to read output I set a breakpoint and used Ctrl-Alt-D afterwards to get at it, which I think is fine for c++).

Comment: @Voo Apparently when I build for x64, even with full optimization, this optimization does not happen. I get `inc dword ptr [a (013F06D410h)] ` directly. See here: http://pastebin.com/zk261Lhf

Comment: @Asaf Huh apparently I got it wrong when I thought I compiled for win32. [See here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7670894/) for the actual code, same bug as you see.

Comment: g++ v4.8.1 seems to have the same bug, if it is a bug (it prints `0` when run with no arguments)

Comment: I filed a bug report at MS Connect: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/900739/a-bug-in-vc-compiler-optimizer-for-loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost a month later, Microsoft still hasn't responded to the [bug in MSDN Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/900739/a-bug-in-vc-compiler-optimizer-for-loops).

To summarize the above comments (and some further tests), apparently it happens in VS2013 professional as well, but the bug only happens when building for Win32, not for x64. The generated assembly code in x64 doesn't have this problem.
So it appears that it is a bug in the optimizer, and that there's no race condition in this code.

Apparently this bug also happens in GCC 4.8.1, but not in GCC 4.9.
(Thanks to [Voo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/144746/voo), [nosid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1305501/nosid) and [Chris Dodd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16406/chris-dodd) for all their testing).

It was suggested to mark `a` as `volatile`. This indeed prevents the bug, but only because it prevents the optimizer from performing the loop register optimization.

I found another solution: Add another local variable `b`, and if needed (and under lock) do the following:

1. Copy `a` into `b`
2. Increment `b` in the loop
3. Copy back to `a` if needed

The optimizer replaces the local variable with a register, so the code is still optimized, but the copies from and to `a` are done **only** if needed, and under lock.

Here's the new `main()` code, with arrows marking the changed lines.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    bool work = (argc == 1);

    int b = 0;          // <----

    if (work)
    {
        m.lock();
        b = a;          // <----
    }

    std::thread th(other);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
    {
        if (i % 7 == 3)
        {
            if (work)
            {
                ++b;    // <----
            }
        }
    }

    if (work)
    {
        a = b;          // <----
        std::cout << a << "\n";
        m.unlock();
    }

    th.join();
}
```

And this is what the assembly code looks like (`&a == 0x000744b0`, `b` replaced with `edi`):

```
    21:     int b = 0;
00071473  xor         edi,edi  
    22: 
    23:     if (work)
00071475  test        bl,bl  
00071477  je          main+5Bh (07149Bh)  
    24:     {
    25:         m.lock();

         ........

00071492  add         esp,4  
    26:         b = a;
00071495  mov         edi,dword ptr ds:[744B0h]  
    27:     }
    28: 

         ........

    33:         {
    34:             if (work)
00071504  test        bl,bl  
00071506  je          main+0C9h (071509h)  
    35:             {
    36:                 ++b;
00071508  inc         edi  
    30:     for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
00071509  inc         esi  
0007150A  cmp         esi,5F5E100h  
00071510  jl          main+0A0h (0714E0h)  
    37:             }
    38:         }
    39:     }
    40: 
    41:     if (work)
00071512  test        bl,bl  
00071514  je          main+10Ch (07154Ch)  
    42:     {
    43:         a = b;
    44:        std::cout << a << "\n";
00071516  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[73084h]  
0007151C  push        edi  
0007151D  mov         dword ptr ds:[744B0h],edi  
00071523  call        dword ptr ds:[73070h]  
00071529  mov         ecx,eax  
0007152B  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (071A80h)  

     ........
```

This keeps the optimization and solves (or works around) the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The 'volatile' keyword will prevent that kind of optimization.  That's exactly what it's for:  every use of 'a' will be read or written exactly as shown, and won't be moved in a different order to other volatile variables.

The implementation of the mutex should include compiler-specific instructions to cause a "fence" at that point, telling the optimizer not to reorder instructions across that boundary.  Since the implementation is not from the compiler vendor, maybe that's left out?  I've never checked.

Since 'a' is global, I would generally think the compiler would be more careful with it.  But, VS10 doesn't know about threads so it won't consider that other threads will use it.  Since the optimizer grasps the entire loop execution, it knows that functions called from within the loop won't touch 'a' and that's enough for it.

I'm not sure what the new standard says about thread visibility of global variables other than volatile.  That is, is there a rule that would prevent that optimization (even though the function can be grasped all the way down so it knows other functions don't use the global, must it assume that other threads can) ?

I suggest trying the newer compiler with the compiler-provided std::mutex, and checking what the C++ standard and current drafts say about that.  I think the above should help you know what to look for.

—John

Comment: Did you even read the question? He IS using std::mutex already. And a mutex is supposed to introduce a memory barrier. And yes, the compilers know about threads. Then, concerning the suggested use of volatile, that connection has been refuted over and over. At most, it is a workaround or a compiler-specific way to create atomically accessible variables, but there aren't even any atomics involved here but plain old mutexes.

Comment: Yes I did read the question.  Including where he wrote, “… I used boost instead of std, …”
I beg to differ: The meaning of volatile is standard and well defined.  It is not only useful, but for pre-x11 compilers arguably required for threaded code to work properly.  It's compiler-specific to work at all without volatile modifier.  Misuse or voodoo use of volatile is wrong when people don't understand what it really means.
By "not know about threads" I mean the detailed stuff in the x11 standard, not just legacy ad-hoc features.

Comment: To clarify, without volatile, the compiler is under no obligation to ever write to the memory at all, or to not do so at arbitrary times.  Without a C++ modifier that's specific for "this variable will be used across threads" (which I agree volatile is not), it is the only portable way to guarantee that it can be used by different threads with ordering expectations and "it really did it" expectations.  It's overkill.  Often in real code the compiler can't optimize non-local variables that way, so it mostly works without volatile.  Volatile does not make a read or write 'atomic'.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the compiler adheres to C++ 11 or to rules imposed by the win32 API, it needs threading support because volatile (which is defined but leaves way to interpretation by implementers) is not sufficient. As far as atomic accesses are concerned, the compile in question uses volatile, but that just as a side note. In any case, if you have proper compiler support for threads, you don't need volatile. So why suggest volatile at all?

Comment: Ulrich, because VS10 uses its own ad-hoc knowledge of threads, and that does not include the idea that global variables may be accessed by multiple threads at the same time.
As I said, a C++03 compiler, although a program may call OS features to produce threads, and may have the standard library enhanced to be mostly safe in that situation, but does not otherwise give thread "visibility" semantics to the rules, then shared variables are not guaranteed to work _without_ volatile.  Non-volatile has no denotational semantics other than to produce the correct answer re eventual volatile accesses.

Comment: “ concerning the suggested use of volatile, that connection has been refuted over and over.”  I don't know what's been claimed here before.

“At most, it is a workaround or a compiler-specific way to create atomically accessible variables”  That multiple threads worked at all was a compiler-specific feature.  'volatile' has nothing to do with atomic, except maybe to give an alignment warning where it normally wouldn't care.  'volatile int' (properly aligned) is atomic to read or write on x86, for example, no differently than 'int' alone.  And 'volatile double' doesn't suddenly become atomic.

Comment: To be clear:  by 'atomic' I mean (only) that if the value is read from memory while something else (another thread, bus mastering transfers, coprocessor, etc) writes to the same address, then it will never see anything other than the old value or the new value; never just some of the bits updated — all or nothing.
Now, in C++03, a real for sure read from the memory backing a variable is a _volatile_ _read_.  Unless declared volatile, there is no guarantee that the variable will really be read at this point, or at all, or even exist in memory.